# Why insert timestamp but shows date in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have insert a couple of rows into Snowflake table, however it returns only date format.

```
INSERT INTO usage (Customer_ID, 
                   Movie_Name, 
                   Movie_Genre, 
                   Movie_Length,  
                   Start_Time, 
                   End_Time) 
       values (1234,    
              'Shrek',   
              'Kids',      
              2.52,
              to_timestamp('12-31-2013 13:33','mm-dd-yyyy HH24:MI'), 
              to_timestamp('12-31-2013 16:04','mm-dd-yyyy HH24:MI')
        );
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What are the types of the `Start_Time` and `End_Time` columns?  What do you mean by returns only date format?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I put date as datetype, should I change to timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from values (1234, 
              'Shrek',   
              'Kids',      
              2.52,
              to_timestamp('12-31-2013 13:33','mm-dd-yyyy HH24:MI'), 
              to_timestamp('12-31-2013 16:04','mm-dd-yyyy HH24:MI')
        );
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 | COLUMN4 | COLUMN5 | COLUMN6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,234 | Shrek | Kids | 2.52 | 2013-12-31 13:33:00.000 | 2013-12-31 16:04:00.000 |

so the `values` block is valid, this implies if you only getting a date, you have a column of type `DATE` or your default format for display timestamps does not have the time part in it anymore.

```
select *, system$typeof(Start_Time) from usage;
```

should show `TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 0):

> *I put date as datetype, should I change to timestamp?*

If the column data type is [DATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#date) the time component is lost during insertion:

> Snowflake supports a single DATE data type for storing dates **(with no time elements).**
>
> **In addition, all accepted TIMESTAMP values are valid inputs for dates; however, the TIME information is truncated.**

In order to preserve both date and time the column data type has to be changed to TIMESTAMP.

---

Sample:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE usage(col DATE, col2 TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO usage(col, col2)
VALUES (to_timestamp('12-31-2013 13:33','mm-dd-yyyy HH24:MI'),
        to_timestamp('12-31-2013 13:33','mm-dd-yyyy HH24:MI'));
        
SELECT * FROM usage;
```

[image]